# org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open while invoking Actions class method sendKeys through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, contextmenu

EDIT: I found the solution. You can't use the right click in Selenium with the native context menu, only custom context menus

Updating the code to right click on a custom context menu, it worked fine.

I have looked at a dozen solutions and none of them work, so I have to share my code. Note, this solution works on my Mac. It does not work on my work laptop (Windows). I am using Chrome, Java 8, and Selenium 3.8.1

```java
@Test
public void contextClickTest() {
    WebElement contextRegion;

    // Arbitrary collection of Keys to execute to navigate context menu
    Keys[] keys = { Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ENTER };

    // this site has a good context click demo
    driver.get("https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html");

    // get the context region of the button using xpath
    contextRegion = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/section/div/div/div/p/span"));

    // Perform action to select some value in the context menu
    Actions act = new Actions(driver).moveToElement(contextRegion).contextClick(contextRegion);
    for(CharSequence cs : keys) {
        act = act.sendKeys(cs);
    }
    act.build().perform();

    // if successful an alert will appear. 
    // If not, this will throw an exception
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
```

What could be the reason for not working when run on a different machine? Do I need to use different Keys for different platforms?

EDIT: This is the exception thrown by failing open the alert window:

```
    FAILED: contextClickTest
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
System info: host: 'Seans-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '10.0.0.104', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fb..., userDataDir: /var/folders/h7/0637cbz907d...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 68.0.3440.106, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: d7788e0a9788a597df727cfbaa4a26bd
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.alert(RemoteWebDriver.java:987)
    at com.revature.testsuites.ContextClickTest.contextClickTest(ContextClickTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Can u try with selenuim version 3.13 or above ?

Comment: I don't think so. In the work environment there are constraints to what I can do. In context this is a maven module branching off of a common framework that manages the dependencies for us.

Changing versions may be seen as non-compliant for any products seeking to leverage the framework I've put together, depending on what management has to say

Comment: Dont think its a problem with Java 8, could be problem with Chrome version being incompatible with the selenium driver you are using, read the docs to see which chrome version ur driver supports.

Comment: I hope not. If it is a limitation in the version then I'll need another method of doing a context-click operations, like using the JavaScriptExecutor

I don't know how I would write that in js though

Comment: @Sean If you want to see chromedriver change notes here is link https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.28/notes.txt

Comment: When you say it does not work on your laptop, can you please post the error which is shown? I can trace it from there related to the Chrome version you have posted.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 there is no error. It just doesn't work. It opens the context menu and that's it. It doesn't send the actual keys

Comment: So the results say that your Test has skipped?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I'll edit the post to include the exception. It's just a NoAlertPresentException though

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no alert open
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to invoke the *Action* class related  methods.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.33*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.33*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v60-62**

- You are using *chrome=68.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v67-69**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.8.1** of **2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z** which is a bit older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_92** which is pretty **ancient**.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u92* , *Selenium Client v3.8.1* , *ChromeDriver v2.33* and the *Chrome Browser v68.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u181**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.14.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.41**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v67-69*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.41 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Answer (score 0):

You may handle it by try-catch where it throws Alert Exception,

**Sample Example:**

```
try {
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
} catch (Exception Ex) {
    System.out.println("Alert was not present");
}
```

Comment: This was not the question, and I'd downvote this answer if I could for multiple reasons

Comment: @Sean If you know solution of your own question, You don't need to consider my answer. FYI, Answers are always based on Experience. Hope it make sense.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. I was replying to this one to tell people it was irrelevant and bad practice